# to depart from the project?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, verbs

Would it be OK to say:
"The Subcontractor `departs` from the certified project" (meaning, that he does not comply with the established work order, stated in the project" and takes his own direction)? Is the word "depart" suitable here?

Comment: I would use a different verb like *deviates from* or *is not compliant with*. The verb *departs from* is ambiguous, as it could also mean *leaves*.

Answer (score 1):

How about "deviates"? It conveys the idea of turning away from a prescribed course:

> deviates — turn from: to turn off from a course or path

Comment: I would be happy to upvote if you were to add a definition or a link to a definition. That is the common approach to single word choices on ELU.